# How to use C++ syntax in python-calling?

Tags: dll, ctypes

I'm trying to call C++ in python using ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary And succeed in calling function and get results.

compiling like that:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -shared func.cpp
```

while python is:

```py
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("./a.exe")
```

But when adding more codes, This calling has failed by winError 1114.
I debug that and found that caused by using syntax:new int[]

```
#include <malloc.h>
void fun(){
    int* p = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*7);
//  int* p = new int[7];
}
```

A knowlage is that using malloc instead can solve this problem like what my code shows.

However, why is that happens?I can't even find Any others beseted in it.

Is that means I can only use C syntax rather than C++ in dll?

Comment: Not a very good idea to name your lib *a.exe*. What is your *OS*? What *Python* version, and what build toolchain is *gcc* part of?

Comment: Operating System  Windows8.1, Python version 3.7, C++ Dev-cpp 5.11 and gcc version 4.9.2. Thank you for advising lib's name but I don't know how to rename that as default rule. I'm new in C++, so should I change to other dev-tools?